# How could i use the utility classes of cake php 2.x in cake php 1.3 or 1.2?

Tags: php, cakephp-1.3, backwards-compatibility, cakephp-2.1

currently i am working on a project which was startted with cakephp 1.2, i have found some changes in in utility classes like File class in version 2.x so i want to use this class with cake 1.2 or 1.3.

please let me know if it is possible, what are the other classes on which this class File is dependent upon.

Comment: Fastest is to just test yourself..? Anyways I think 2.1 should have all the utility functions 1.x have.

Comment: i want to use additional functions and features of cake's utility library 2.x.

Comment: migrate to cake 2, it is much more consistant than the 1.2/1.3, using the upgrade shell is a bit tricky, but you'll get a much more mature system in change ;-)